# ZPOOL Mirror setup

Tags: zfs, hard-drive, zpool

What is the best setup for an zpool intended for database big inserts or TCP/IP dumps (i mean **sustained** high write throughput using 4 disks ?

I want buy 4 Wd RE4 2TB drives and get the more power i can !

i think of

```
zpool create tank mirror disk1 disk2 disk3 disk4
```

OR

```
zpool create tank mirror disk1 disk2 mirror disk3 disk4
```

OR

```
zpool create tank disk1 disk2 disk3 disk4
```

i think the solution with two mirror in a pool is the best, but not sure.

**edit :** ok so mirror IS RAID1. It is not possible to make this setup : RAID0 (RAID0, RAID0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The three commands and ZFS setups you've listed are vastly different configurations.

```
zpool create tank mirror disk1 disk2 disk3 disk4
```

This creates a 4-way mirror with the capacity of ONE disk. Lots of protection, less space and less performance. 
*I don't think you want that.*

```
zpool create tank mirror disk1 disk2 mirror disk3 disk4
```

This creates a stripe of two RAID 1 mirrors - RAID 1+0, with a capacity of TWO disks. 
*This is a good balance.*

```
zpool create tank disk1 disk2 disk3 disk4
```

This creates a stripe of four disks - RAID 0, no protection against failure and a capacity of FOUR disks. 
*This is fast, but only make sense if you don't care about your data's integrity. If a drive fails, you will lose all of your data*

Comment: I best understand now. I thought it was possible to make raid0 of raid0 but mirror is RAID1 not RAID0

Comment: RAID0 (RAID0, RAID0) is the same as a three-way stripe... so `zpool create tank disk1 disk2 disk3 disk4` would be all RAID 0, and thus, the fastest. But there would not be any data protection.

Comment: OK Thanks. For me the best setup for programing/ research is two zpool: a 5400rpm raidz with l2arc ssd for all data and stripping with 10k disk no ssd l2arc for serious work. I mean the raidz pool can handle backup from the stripped pool.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how mirror and striping work:

- If you want more write throughput, then more stripes
- If you want more fault tolerance and read performance, then more mirrors

So with 4 disks, the best way to achieve the most throughput without sacrificing fault tolerance is to create 2 mirrors, allowing the data to stripe over the mirrored pairs.

To take this further, if you had six disks, this configuration would give you more write performance:

```
zpool create tank mirror disk1 disk2 mirror disk3 disk4 mirror disk5 disk6
```

And this would give you more fault tolerance:

```
zpool create tank mirror disk1 disk2 disk3 mirror disk4 disk5 disk6
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you'll do massive writes (vs a lot of small random writes), raidz might be a good space/redundancy compromise:

```
zpool create tank raidz disk1 disk2 disk3 disk4
```

Capacity of three disks, survives one disk failure.

Comment: yeah, i have already a raidz of 5 1Tb caviar green but write IOPS seems not sufficient (for me). And you are limited with record size, expecialy on raidz and 4k drives.

Comment: @Avlin Side note: RAIDz is RAM hungry, you'll get marginal performance unless you throw gigs of RAM at it. The processor has to be decent as well...

Comment: That's it : raidz for movies and backup, zpool stripping and mirroring for databases and VMs.

Comment: I understood the question to be about throughput (a small number of big writes) while if the goal is iops (a large number of small writes), raidz is indeed not optimal.